# Why does include? for Ruby return false?

Tags: ruby, string, byebug

I have the following Ruby fragment from a byebug session:

```
(byebug) target_name
"foo/"
(byebug) target_name.class
String
(byebug) target_name.include?('/')
false
(byebug) "foo/".include?('/')
true
```

Why does the `include?` method return `false` as `/` is part of `foo/`?

Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? I just tried to replicate this and can't

Comment: @JamieG ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that `target_string` contains some non-ascii characters.

For example compare:

```
irb(main):019:0>> str = "foo/"
=> "foo/"
irb(main):020:0> str.ascii_only?
=> true
irb(main):021:0> str.include?("/")
=> true
```

and

```
irb(main):022:0> str = "foo\xe2\x88\x95"
=> "foo∕"
irb(main):023:0> str.ascii_only?
=> false
irb(main):024:0> str.include?("/")
=> false
```

In the latter example the string contains the "forward slash" `U+2215` character encoded as utf-8 bytes.

Depending on your specific use case, you could e.g. convert the string to ascii and blindly replace any undefined or invalid character with a `/`.

```
str.encode("ascii", "utf-8", replace: "/")
```

Look at the [`#encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-encode) method for more options.

Comment: I checked the binary values of the text in the question, though.